# How to extract the date from the file name using python

Tags: python, regex, csv, datetime

How to extract date from the CSV below.

```
date       time     Air_Temp    Barometric_Press    Dew_Point   Relative_Humidity   Wind_Dir    Wind_Gust   Wind_Speed
2012_01_01 00:02:14 34.30   30.50   26.90   74.20   346.40  11.00    3.60
2012_01_01 00:08:29 34.10   30.50   26.50   73.60   349.00  12.00    8.00
2012_01_01 00:14:45 33.90   30.60   26.80   75.00   217.80  12.00    9.20
```

My code, I am able to extract the first column successfully. I need to find the date and time.

The name of the CSV is data_2012.

```
datetime_list, barpress_list = [], []
datetime_re = re.compile(r'[\d]{2,4}') # regex to get datetime info

for year in range(2012, 2013):
            fname = 'dataa_{0}.txt'.format(year)
            print('Loading {0}'.format(fname))
            for row in DictReader(open(fname,'r'),delimiter='\t'):
                barpress_list.append(float(row['Barometric_Press']))
                #datetime_list.append((datetime(#####need to insert))))))
```

Output of datetime_list:

```
[datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 2, 14),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 8, 29),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 14, 45)]
```

Comment: so what are you trying to achieve ? only the date from the datetime_list or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get datetime data like this:

```
In [1]: import csv

In [2]: import datetime

In [3]: with open('del.csv') as f:
    ...:     csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
    ...:     next(csv_reader)
    ...:     for row in csv_reader:
    ...:         dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('-'.join(row[:2]), '%Y_%m_%d-%H:%M:%S')
    ...:         print(dt)

2012-01-01 00:02:14
2012-01-01 00:08:29
2012-01-01 00:14:45
```

`del.csv`: Name of your csv file

`dt`: a Python datetime object